# Django Haystack - Searching for foreign key

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-haystack

I am trying to use haystack to search for all the names of phones that match a query but also match all the phones if the creator of the phone was searched for which happens to be a foreign key in my database. I have not been able to get a search for a foreign key to work. Am I doing something wrong in my code below?

models.py

```
class Phone(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(Creator, db_column=u'creator_fid', blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_column=u'phone')
```

search_indexes.py

```
class PhoneIndex(SearchIndex):
    text = CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    creator = CharField(model_attr='creator')
```

**FIX** --- We were using the 'simple' backend and for whatever reason, once we switched ti 'whoosh', and added a HAYSTACK_WOOSH_PATH, it worked. Thanks.

Comment: How does the Creator class look like? What data is stored in creator_fid?